# Как отсортировать массив объектов по количеству свойств в нем?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, сортировка

У нас есть массив объектов с определенным количеством свойств в них, нужно отсортировать по возрастанию от меньшего к большему

```
var objectArray = [{a : 'a', b : 'b'}, {a : 'a'}, {a : 'a', b : 'b', c : 'c'}]; 

//вот что по идее должно получится на выходе
// [{a : 'a'}, {a : 'a', b : 'b'}, {a : 'a', b : 'b', c : 'c'}]
```

Comment: Есть какие либо здравые идеи по этому поводу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Логично использовать метод [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), сортируя по размерности объектов

```js
var objectArray = [{a : 'a', b : 'b'}, {a : 'a'}, {a : 'a', b : 'b', c : 'c'}]; 

objectArray.sort(function(a, b) {  
  return Object.keys(a).length - Object.keys(b).length;
});

console.log(objectArray);
```

Comment: Я даже не думал, что все так просто будет. Начал изобретать велосипед и кстати да, использовал sort() в нем. Спасибо :)